# Fixed container positioned on top of the body's scroll

Tags: css, fixed

We are experencing Fixed container positioned on top of the body's scroll ( even with: `box-sizing: border-box;`), with those styles:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
z-index: 100;
width: 100%;
height: 71px;
background-color: #115191;
box-shadow: 0 0px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

[image]

but if I set the width, like this:

`width: calc(100% - 17px )`

then is what we expect ( at least in chrome, other browsers/versions must have a different scroll width)

[image]

The styles of html tag:

```
height: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
```

body:

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
min-height: 100%;
```

any idea wha'ts causing this and how to prevent it?

thanks

Comment: and what is the style of the fixed element?

Comment: edited with those, but bascically  `width:100%; top: 0; position:fixed;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove scroll from `html`, `body` elements and add it to content wrapper. In this example it is `main` element.

Html example

```
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    <!--All page content goes here-->
  </main>
</body>
```

Remove dafault page scroll

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add scroll and height for content wrapper

```
main {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

`40px` here is the height of the fixed header.

```
header {
  ...
  height: 40px;
  ...
}
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /*Some reset styles*/
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

main {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow: auto;
}

header, main {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Title 2</h2>
  <h3>Title 3</h3>
  <p>The Lost World is a novel released in 1912 by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle concerning an expedition to a plateau in the Amazon basin of South America where prehistoric animals (dinosaurs and other extinct creatures) still survive. It was originally published serially in the popular Strand Magazine and illustrated by New-Zealand-born artist Harry Rountree during the months of April–November 1912. The character of Professor Challenger was in thrusting book. The novel also describes a war between indigenous people and a vicious tribe of ape-like creatures.</p>
  <p>The Lost World is a novel released in 1912 by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle concerning an expedition to a plateau in the Amazon basin of South America where prehistoric animals (dinosaurs and other extinct creatures) still survive. It was originally published serially in the popular Strand Magazine and illustrated by New-Zealand-born artist Harry Rountree during the months of April–November 1912. The character of Professor Challenger was in thrusting book. The novel also describes a war between indigenous people and a vicious tribe of ape-like creatures.</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to see all your code, but you probably have `margin:0` at the html/body. Without it, it works

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.content{
  height: 2000px
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

When I add the margin I got the same problem you experience

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.content{
  height: 2000px
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```